# Biased coin flipping?

Tags: python

What is the simplest (does not have to be fastest) way to do a biased random choice between True and False in Python? By "biased", I mean where either True or False is more probable based on a probability I set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's pretty easy **and** fast:

```
import random

def biased_flip(prob_true=0.5):
    return random.random() < prob_true
```

Of course if you just call `biased_flip()` you'll get `True` and `False` with 50% probability each, but e.g `biased_flip(0.8)` will give you about eight `True`s for each `False` in the long run.